# Hashing a list of 64 bit int so list[n] % len yields unique values in range 0:len-1

Tags: c, hash, bit-manipulation

The title may leave something to be desired, my apologies. The best I could come up with.

My initial idea was to "simply" shuffle the bits of a given list of 64 bit integers in a way so that each item%length would yield an unique index.
My initial approach was reasonably simple too.
I'm a big fan of the delta swap function and have been for years (curtesy of chessprogramming.org):

```
/**
 * swap any none overlapping pairs of bits
 *   that are delta places apart
 * @param b any bitboard
 * @param mask has a 1 on the least significant position
 *             for each pair supposed to be swapped
 * @param delta of pairwise swapped bits
 * @return bitboard b with bits swapped
 */
U64 deltaSwap(U64 b, U64 mask, int delta) {
   U64 x = (b ^ (b >> delta)) & mask;
   return   x ^ (x << delta)  ^ b;
}
```

and I rather thought that I could do it with a limited set of very specific masks and delta value pairs, and a specific number of iterations to achieve a lookup time complexity on the resulting hash table of N(1).
After a whole lot of experimentation, I actually started thinking and realized that 64!, which I think is the number of ways of shuffling the aforementioned bits, is a rather large number, and hoping to represent a given shuffle pattern in any reasonably way, might be impossible.

Further thinking about this, I've almost reached the conclusion that to yield the desired result, I need only shuffle the lower 32 bits, perhaps even lower, considering what I really intent to use it on, i.e. memory adresses, but still, it remains a rather large number, and my initial assumption that a short list of delta values, which an accompanying list of masks could represents the "hashing seed" is of course ludicrous.

For completeness sake the list of masks mentioned, 64 in total including what you might call a noop mask, can be generate using this cute little function. I created a recursive version I couldn't help being a little proud of at some point in the past, but forgot how, so no brilliance to be found here:

```
uint64_t getMask( int d )
{
    static const uint64_t m[6] = {
        0x5555555555555555,
        0x3333333333333333,
        0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f,
        0x00ff00ff00ff00ff,
        0x0000ffff0000ffff,
        0x00000000ffffffff
    };
    uint64_t t = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    for( int i = 0, j = d; i < 6 && j; ++i, j >>= 1 )
        if( j&1 ) t &= m[i];
    //if( ( d&64 )  && ( ( ( d-1 )&d )^64) ) t <<= ((~d)+1)&d;
    /*
    an additional set of "sister masks", where the accompanying delta must be
    d-2*LSB, or d-2*((-d)&d), stripping the top bit also, ^64, naturally.
    can be achieved including this conditional and increasing the upper bound to 127.
    When d is a power of 2, for range 64:127, the mask will be a repeat of d^64.
    */
    return  t;
}
```

I mistakenly thought that 6 iterations could do the trick. It seemed so obvious, but of course that should have been the first red flag.

The origin of this "pattern" is a long lived obsession with bitboards and their rotational symmetries in n dimensions.

After all this rambling, and I am sorry, but there just is no other way for this particular Autist to express himself, my conclusions is simple.
I have no idea how, or if it is even possible to achieve the desired result, without shuffling each bit individually, and most certainly my approach is entirely wrong, but I can't think of any other way, thus I finally, after a couple of months of avoiding just that, knowing full well how my particular and rather verbose way of asking questions is usually received on sites such as this, usually pan out.

Hoping for your indulgence (probably not the right word) and advice.

Best regards.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [perfect hash function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). Here is a Stack Overflow search for [perfect hash](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22perfect+hash%22).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't know of the concept of a "perfect hash function". To my mind, what this implies, is obviously impossible. I was thinking that since the input is the same length as the output, the it might just be possible.
At any rate, thanks for the attention. I will certainly take a look at those links.